# How to generate RSA private key using Fernet

Tags: python, cryptography, fernet

This should be simple (famous last words)

In the terminal, i can run this command:

winpty openssl genrsa -des3 -out my_rsa_key_pair 2048

How can I do the exact same thing using [pyca/cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fernet method is not used as a method for generating RSA keys. Therefore, Fernet-based RSA key generation is not supported by pyca/cryptography. However, you can generate RSA keys in the pyca/cryptography package like this:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537, # Commonly used public exponent
    key_size=2048, # Key size in bits
    backend=default_backend()
)

public_key = private_key.public_key()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry had to go with the other one because it incorporates the password which is a requirement for me.  thanks though

Comment: hmm, it seems the post which had the answer has been deleted. Also it was not working i found out...

Comment: haha oh dang, I wonder why it was deleted. What did you need from the other solution?